# TypeError: Cannot read property 'extend' of undefined при тестировании jest

Tags: javascript, vue.js, typescript, nuxt.js, jest

Пытаюсь запустить простой тест компонента на jest, чтобы проверить что я правильно настроила конфиг.
Подскажите как можно обойти эту проблему, из за чего она появляется?
Стек vue, nuxt, ts
Код текста:

```js
import { mount } from '@vue/test-utils'

import { CloseIcon } from '~/components/shared/icon/close-icon'
import { localVue } from '~/jest/config'

const propsData = {
    whenClick: () => {},
}
const wrapper = mount(CloseIcon, {
    propsData,
    localVue,
})

describe('CloseIcon', () => {
    test('является инстансом vue', () => {
        expect(wrapper.vm).toBeTruthy()
    })
})
```

Скрин ошибки:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Текст ощибки:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'extend' of undefined

  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/@fe-ui/fragment/fragment.tsx:3:29)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/@fe-ui/fragment/index.ts:1:1)
```

Само место ошибки в плагине:

```js
import Vue from 'vue'

export const Fragment = Vue.extend({
    functional: true,
    render(_, context) {
        return context.children
    },
}) as new () => {
    $props: {
        key?: string | number
    }
}
```

Jest.config :

```js
module.exports = {
    preset: '@fe/jest-config',
    testEnvironment: 'node',
    moduleNameMapper: {
        '^(?:~|@)/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/$1',
        '.css': 'identity-obj-proxy',
    },
    moduleFileExtensions: [
        'js',
        'json',
        'vue',
        'ts',
        'tsx',
    ],
    modulePaths: [
        '<rootDir>/src/',
        '<rootDir>/node_modules/',
    ],
    transform: {
        '.*\\.(vue)$': 'vue-jest',
        '^.+\\.(js|ts)$': 'babel-jest',
        '^.+\\.tsx?$': 'ts-jest',
        '.+\\.(svg|png|jpg|ttf|woff|woff2)$': 'jest-transform-stub',
    },
    transformIgnorePatterns: [
        '<rootDir>/node_modules/?!(vue-class-decorator)',
    ],
    setupFiles: ['./setup.js'],
    snapshotSerializers: ['jest-serializer-html'],
    globals: {
        'ts-jest': {
            babelConfig: true,
        },
    },
}
```

Babel.config для jest:

```js
module.exports = {
    presets: [
        [
            '@babel/preset-env',
            {
                targets: {
                    node: 'current',
                },
            },
        ],
        '@babel/preset-typescript',
        '@vue/babel-preset-jsx',
    ],
    plugins: [
        ['@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators', {
            'legacy': true,
        }],
        'const-enum',
    ],
    overrides: [{
        include: /node_modules\/vue-class-decorator/,
    }],
}
```

Comment: Добавьте код текстом, а не скриншотами

Comment: @AlexeyTen исправила

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса